# Can I limit the number of times a character appears in a string?

Tags: c#, string, char, substring

For instance, I have a string and I only want the character '<' to appear 10 times in the string, and create a substring where the cutoff point is the 10th appearance of that character. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: sure; you could keep using IndexOf to find whether it is there 10 times, or you could write a regex, or you could "split" it, or...

Answer (score 0):

A manual solution could be like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int maxNum = 10;
        string initialString = "a<b<c<d<e<f<g<h<i<j<k<l<m<n<o<p<q<r<s<t<u<v<w<x<y<z";
        string[] splitString = initialString.Split('<');
        string result = "";
        Console.WriteLine(splitString.Length);
        if (splitString.Length > maxNum)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {
                result += splitString[i];
                result += "<";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = initialString;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

By the way, it may be better to try to do it using Regex (in case you may have other replacement rules in the future, or need to make changes, etc). However, given your problem, something like that will work, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `TakeWhile` for your purpose, given the string `s`, your character `<` as `c` and your count `10` as `count`, following function would solve your problem:

```
public static string foo(string s, char c, int count)
{
    var i = 0;
    return string.Concat(s.TakeWhile(x => (x == c ? i++ : i) < count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches) can be used to count the number of occurrences of a patter in a string.
It also reference the position of each occurrence, the [Capture.Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index) property.
You can read the Index of the `Nth` occurrence and cut your string there:
(The [`RegexOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions) are there just in case the pattern is something different. Modify as required.)

```
int cutAtOccurrence = 10;
string input = "one<two<three<four<five<six<seven<eight<nine<ten<eleven<twelve<thirteen<fourteen<fifteen";

var regx = Regex.Matches(input, "<", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (regx.Count >= cutAtOccurrence) {
    input = input.Substring(0, regx[cutAtOccurrence - 1].Index);
}
```

`input` is now:

```
one<two<three<four<five<six<seven<eight<nine<ten
```

If you need to use this procedure many times, it's bettern to build a method that returns a `StringBuilder` instead.